# Changing the position of a Power Apps Form to the middle of the page

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

When I create a new PowerApps form, a separate window is pulled up, but I cannot move it to the middle of my screen- it seems locked to the right.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to change the position of PowerApps form (or the default list form) in SharePoint list.

If you are open for customization, you can build custom list forms using SPFx.
See what customizations are supported for customization: [Supported customizations on "modern" team sites.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites#supported-customizations-on-modern-team-sites)

Sample reference: [SharePoint Framework (SPFx) React Controls : Creating custom list form including People picker and Taxonomy picker.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51748.sharepoint-framework-spfx-react-controls-creating-custom-list-form-including-people-picker-and-taxonomy-picker.aspx)